# How to avoid parent ScrollView to clip internal ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When a horizontal child ScrollView is nested inside a vertical parent ScrollView, internal element is clipped by parent ScrollView.
Is there currently (Xcode 11.4) a way to change this behavior?
[image: clipped when nested]

It's works as expected when ScrollView is not nested. (commented out the parent)
Red element is drawn over SafeArea.

[image: not clipped when nested]

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible approach to consider.

*However there is a drawback - bug seems in SwiftUI, on change orientation to portrait horizontal scrollview has got unexpected offset (internal, because by borders all external is ok). I haven't find workaround for this yet, but... anyway*

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { i in
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                            HStack {
                                ForEach(0..<10) { j in
                                    Color.red.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                }
                            }
                        }.background(Color.blue)
                    }
                }.frame(width: gp.size.width)
            }.background(Color.green)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    }
```