# Why does an SwiftUI horizontal ScrollView inside of a vertical ScrollView refuse to ignore the insets on Landscape mode?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I start with the following horizontal ScrollView in SwiftUI and, testing it on an iPhone 11 in Landscape mode, I see that even though the ScrollView's frame respect both `.leading` and `.trailing` insets, when scrolling through the elements inside, these do show up behind the notch and outside the limits of the ScrollView.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack {
        ForEach(1..<20) { index in
            Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).opacity(0.5)
        }
    }
}.background(Color(.red)).opacity(1)
```

This is desired behaviour, and I see it happening in apps like Shortcuts, or photos for iOS 13. However, when I embed the above into a Vertical ScrollView and test in the same conditions:

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(1..<20) { index in
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).opacity(0.5)
                }
            }
        }.background(Color(.red)).opacity(1)
    }
}.background(Color(.blue)).opacity(0.5)
```

In this case the elements inside the horizontal ScrollView never go outside the parent ScrollView. If I try `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` on the parent ScrollView and I start the app on Landscape, after the first interaction there seems to be some repositioning, but then the horizontal ScrollView shows up clipped when rotating to Portrait mode.

Why is this happening and how can I achieve the desired behaviour? (E.G.: elements of the Horizontal ScrollView showing up outside of their ScrollView's limits when scrolling, but everything else remaining respectful of the `SafeArea`)

Comment: Might be helpful [How to avoid parent ScrollView to clip internal ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159066/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi thanks, that gets me to the same point in which I was trying with  `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`, when going back to portrait mode the horizontal ScrollViews appear clipped. it does seem like a bug to me...